# calculated field in tableau dependent on values in column

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm new to Tableau so could have this all wrong, i'm trying to create a calculated field which works out the percentage of 'completed' tasks.

My data looks like

```
Date |   Department | Task |  Task Status       |  Number of Items
5/11      HR           one    one (complete)        5
5/11      HR           one    one (in progress)     3
5/11      HR           one    one (not started)     1
5/11      HR           two    two (complete)        3
5/11      HR           two    two (in progress)     6
5/11      HR           two    two (not started)     9
5/11      Finance      one    one (complete)        3
5/11      Finance      one    one (in progress)     2
5/11      Finance      one    one (not started)     8
```

I'm trying to work out the percentage of completed tasks for each department so for example in HR it is 8/27 tasks are completed. This data is updated every week so i'd like to know it for the most recent date. There are only 2 tasks. What I have so far is

```
IF [Date] == #05/11# 
THEN 
SUM(IF [Task Status] == 'one (complete)' OR [Task Status] =='two (complete)' THEN [Number of Items] 
END)
/SUM([Number of Items]
END
```

However it is throwing a 'Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparison or results in IF expressions.' error

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working at level of aggregation shown at level of detail.  Therefore you need to add LOD calculated field here.  Do it like this-

```
{FIXED [Date], [Department] : sum(IF [Task Status] = 'one (complete)' OR [Task Status] ='two (complete)' THEN
[Number of Items] End)}/{FIXED [Date], [Department] : sum([Number of Items])}
```

sample data given

[image]

Adding this field in front of date and department column, in a view, will give you desired ratio.

[image]

Good luck

p.s. this will give you ratio for every date.  If you need this ratio for one date, filter out other dates from view

Comment: thank you, I didn't realise there were LOD expressions

Answer (score 0):

2 options.

1. Wrap [Date] in ATTR(), so it would be IF ATTR([Date])=...
2. Rewrite your calculation and make use of [boolean calculations](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-boolean-data-type/):

SUM(INT([Date] == #05/11# AND RIGHT([Task Status],10)="(complete)"))/SUM(INT([Date] == #05/11#))